# I have a multiple choice with if/else statment but due to function validation, it is not proceeding to the next question after i click No

Tags: javascript

During the question.
When I click "No" it not letting me proceed with the next question.
Due to function validation on input placeholder for if I clicked "Yes".

How to remove the validation when "click Yes" question is hidden?

```js
function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".toggle-trigger").change(function(event) {
            $(".toggle-trigger").each(function(index, element) {
                var $element = $(element);
                var $toggleArea = $($element.data("toggle-area"));

                if($element.is(":checked")) {
                    $toggleArea.show();
                } else {
                    $toggleArea.hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="tab">
    Are you buying a home with someone else?
    <label><input class="toggle-trigger" type="radio" name="q1" value="No" oninput="this.className = ''" data-toggle-area="#q1-no"/>No</label>
    <label><input class="toggle-trigger" type="radio" name="q1" value="Yes" data-toggle-area="#q1-yes" />Yes</label>
    <br><br>
      <div id="q1-yes" style="display:none;">
        What is the Co-borrower contact info?
        <p><input type="email" placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Full Name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fullname"></p>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which validation are you talking about ?

Comment: You can use `$(x[currentTab]).find("input:visible")` to skip inputs that are hidden.

Comment: It didnt work. When i click 'no" it dont let me go to the nest question.

Comment: I need to fill into the placeholder on the "yes' to go to next question.

Answer (score 1):

The contact form don't show because you are change in a loop and it only show contact form only both input are selected. So i change your code into check value on change and it don't care if value are Yes or No if you selected it show contacts

```html
<div class="tab">
  Are you buying a home with someone else?
  <label><input
      class="toggle-trigger"
      type="radio"
      name="q1"
      value="No"
      data-toggle-area="#q1-no"
    />No</label
  >
  <label
    ><input
      class="toggle-trigger"
      type="radio"
      name="q1"
      value="Yes"
      data-toggle-area="#q1-yes"
    />Yes</label
  >
  <br /><br />
  <div id="contactForm" style="display: none;">
    What is the Co-borrower contact info?
    <p>
      <input
        type="email"
        placeholder="E-mail..."
        oninput="this.className = ''"
        name="email"
      />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input
        placeholder="Phone..."
        oninput="this.className = ''"
        name="phone"
      />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input
        placeholder="Full Name..."
        oninput="this.className = ''"
        name="fullname"
      />
    </p>
  </div>
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
  ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input:radio[name='q1']")
            .change(function (event) {
     //&& this.value == 'Yes' -- add to condition if you want contacts form only show when value == Yes or no 
              if (this.checked) {
           $(contactForm).show();
}
      })
    });
  </script>
</div>
```